# Entity Framework with composite key: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is my model:

```
[Key, Column(Order=1)] // composite key with ExternalId. WebshopId+ExternalId must be unique
[ForeignKey("Webshop_Id")]
public virtual Webshop WebshopEntity
{
    get { return _Webshop; }
    set { _Webshop = value; }
}

[NotMapped]
private Webshop _Webshop;

public int Webshop_Id { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
[MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "ExternalId must be atleast 1 character")]
public virtual string ExternalId { get; set; }
```

`Product` should have a composite primary key of Webshop (it's parent) and `ExternalId`.

Now that my database is filled, I'm adding a new `Product` with the same `ExternalId` but a different `Webshop` as parent. This causes the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Products'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value is (110).

What am I doing wrong? (using EF6)

Comment: Can you post DDL SQL of your dbo.Products table?

Comment: Try defining the [Key] on Webshop_Id instead of on WebshopEntity.

Comment: Well that was the problem, [Key] on Webshop_id did the trick.
The table definition now shows
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Webshop_Id] ASC, [ExternalId] ASC),
while before this change it was missing the Webshop_Id ASC part.
Thanks! (submit it as answer if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Key]` annotation should be defined on `Webshop_Id` and not on `WebshopEntity`.